What is wrong with my voxel terrain generator. Terrain generator is not making seamless terrain
So as the title says, I'm making a voxel engine using rust and bevy and I am currently working on the terrain generation. I decided to use a heightmap that was made using simplex noise. This is how a world size of 4x1x4 chunks looks at the moment.
Not flattering at all.
After looking around the internet I saw that for seamless terrain, the seeds for the chunks have to be calculated based on the chunk position which I did here.
    fn calculate_seed(&self, chunk_pos: &IVec3) -> u64 {
        let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
        chunk_pos.hash(&mut hasher);
        hasher.finish()
    }

    pub fn create_chunk_heightmap(&mut self, chunk_pos: IVec3) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut heightmap: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity((CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE) as usize); // vector preallocation
        let seed = self.calculate_seed(&chunk_pos);
        let mut noise: FastNoise = FastNoise::seeded(seed);
        noise.set_noise_type(NoiseType::Simplex);
        noise.set_frequency(0.1);

        for x in 0..CHUNK_SIZE {
            for z in 0..CHUNK_SIZE {
                // Get voxel X and Z position in global space
                let voxel_x = chunk_pos.x * CHUNK_SIZE + x;
                let voxel_z = chunk_pos.z * CHUNK_SIZE + z;
                let noise_value = noise.get_noise(voxel_x as f32 / 32.0, voxel_z as f32 / 32.0);
                //println!("Noise Value: {}", noise_value);
                let normalized_noise_value = (noise_value + 1.0) / 2.0;
                let scaled_noise_value = normalized_noise_value * 32.0;
                let final_noise_value = scaled_noise_value as i32;
                // Apply to heightmap
                heightmap.push(final_noise_value);
            }
        }

        return heightmap;
    }


Then after that, each voxel is going to be allocated based on its index in the heightmap as so
pub fn create_chunk_voxels(&mut self, chunk_pos: IVec3, heightmap: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<Voxel> {
        let mut voxels: Vec<Voxel> =
            Vec::with_capacity((CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE) as usize); // vector preallocation

        for x in 0..CHUNK_SIZE {
            for z in 0..CHUNK_SIZE {
                for y in 0..CHUNK_SIZE {
                    let voxel_id = x * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE + y * CHUNK_SIZE + z;
                    let voxel_y = chunk_pos.y * CHUNK_SIZE + y;
                    let heightmap_index = (x * CHUNK_SIZE + z) as usize;
                    let heightmap_value = heightmap[heightmap_index];

                    let is_solid = voxel_y <= heightmap_value;
                    let voxel = Voxel {
                        id: voxel_id,
                        is_solid,
                    };
                    voxels.push(voxel);
                }
            }
        }

        return voxels;
    }

    pub fn generate_chunk_v2(&mut self, chunk_pos: IVec3) -> Chunk {
        let heightmap = self.create_chunk_heightmap(chunk_pos);
        // println!("Heightmap: {:?}", heightmap);
        let voxels = self.create_chunk_voxels(chunk_pos, heightmap);
        let chunk = Chunk { voxels };
        return chunk;
    }

    pub fn generate_terrain_v2(&mut self, world_size: IVec3) {
        for x in 0..world_size.x {
            for z in 0..world_size.z {
                for y in 0..world_size.y {
                    let chunk_pos: IVec3 = IVec3::new(x, y, z);
                    let chunk = self.generate_chunk_v2(chunk_pos);
                    self.insert_chunk(chunk_pos, chunk);
                }
            }
        }
    }

I am currently unaware if the problem is from my implementation or I am missing something as I have pondered on this problem for the past three days. I request some assistance. Thank you

What's wrong with the question you asked before that's just like this one?

I think this got automatically posted from the staging grounds. My bad

Your terrain is not seamless because you are generating a new seed for each chunk. To fix this you would need to generate a global seed which all chunks use, rather than unique seeds for every chunk.
